# PHP: Get n-th item of an associative array

Tags: php, associative-array

If you have an associative array:

```
Array
(
    [uid] => Marvelous
    [status] => 1
    [set_later] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 0
        )

    [op] => Submit
    [submit] => Submit
)
```

And you want to access the 2nd item, how would you do it? `$arr[1]` doesn't seem to be working:

```
foreach ($form_state['values']['set_later'] as $fieldKey => $setLater) {
    if (! $setLater) {
        $valueForAll = $form_state['values'][$fieldKey];
        $_SESSION[SET_NOW_KEY][array_search($valueForAll, $form_state['values'])] = $valueForAll; // this isn't getting the value properly
    }
}
```

This code is supposed to produce:

```
$_SESSION[SET_NOW_KEY]['status'] = 1
```

But it just produces a blank entry.

Comment: Is it possible to change the keys in set_later to be the field names? so $form_state['values']['set_later'] = array( 'uid' => 1, 'status' => 0 )? That would solve the problem and remove the need for array_search.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Use [`array_slice`](http://php.net/array_slice)

```
$second = array_slice($array, 1, 1, true);  // array("status" => 1)

// or

list($value) = array_slice($array, 1, 1); // 1

// or

$blah = array_slice($array, 1, 1); // array(0 => 1)
$value = $blah[0];
```

Comment: Setting array_slice()'s perserve_keys param seems to have no effect for me: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/05e880de8805ff45f652743e1a309f598fac245f -- Instead of returning a keyed array I'd like to be able to access the value like $blah[0] (as in the example above). Instead, I still have to lookup the value I'm after by its key, not position.

Comment: For my application I needed to both look up the nth item and remove it, and ended up realising that `array_splice` (as opposed to `array_slice`) does both!

Comment: The last option doesnt seem to work as describbed. Looking at the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php), they state *preserve_keys:  Note that array_slice() will reorder and reset the numeric array indices by default. You can change this behaviour by setting preserve_keys to TRUE.* This means that the last option results in `array("status" => 1)`

Comment: @nickf: Same problem as in other comments above, In your last example, last parameter must bu `false` to tell php _not_ to preserve keys. In your first example, you must add a last parameter `true` to get the result with this preserved "status" key (as no param = default = false = reindexed to 0)

Answer (score 17):

I am a bit confused.  Your code does not appear to have the correct keys for the array.  However, if you wish to grab just the second element in an array, you could use:

```
$keys = array_keys($inArray);
$key = $keys[1];
$value = $inArray[$key];
```

However, after considering what it appears you're trying to do, something like this might work better:

```
$ii = 0;
$setLaterArr = $form_state['values']['set_later'];
foreach($form_state['values'] as $key => $value) {
    if($key == 'set_later')
        continue;
    $setLater = $setLaterArr[$ii];
    if(! $setLater) {
        $_SESSION[SET_NOW_KEY][$key] = $value;
    }
    $ii ++;
}
```

Does that help?  It seems you are trying to set the session value if the set_later value is not set.  The above code does this.  Instead of iterating through the inner array, however, it iterates through the outer array and uses an index to track where it is in the inner array.  This should be reasonably performant.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`array_slice`](https://www.php.net/array_slice) to get the second item:

```
$a= array(
 'hello'=> 'world',
 'how'=> 'are you',
 'an'=> 'array',
);

$second= array_slice($a, 1, 1, true);
var_dump($second);
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a one line way to do it with [array_slice](https://secure.php.net/array_slice) and [current](https://secure.php.net/current)

```
$value = current(array_slice($array, 1, 1)); // returns value only
```

Answer (score 0):

If the array you provide in the first example corresponds to $form_state then

```
$form_state['values']['set_later'][1]
```

will work.

Otherwise

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($form_state['values']['set_later'] as $fieldKey => $setLater) {
    if ($i == 1) {
        $valueForAll = $form_state['values'][$fieldKey];
        $_SESSION[SET_NOW_KEY][$fieldKey] = $setLater;
        continue;
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every one of the responses here are focused on getting the second element, independently on how the array is formed.

If this is your case.

```
Array
(
    [uid] => Marvelous
    [status] => 1
    [set_later] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 0
        )

    [op] => Submit
    [submit] => Submit
)
```

Then you can get the value of the second element via `$array['status']`.

Also this code

```
foreach ($form_state['values']['set_later'] as $fieldKey => $setLater) {
    if (! $setLater) {
        $valueForAll = $form_state['values'][$fieldKey];
        $_SESSION[SET_NOW_KEY][array_search($valueForAll, $form_state['values'])] = $valueForAll; // this isn't getting the value properly
    }
}
```

I don't understand what are you trying to do, care to explain?

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
         * Get nth item from an associative array
         * 
         * 
         * @param     $arr
         * @param int $nth
         *
         * @return array
         */
        function getNthItemFromArr($arr, $nth = 0){
            $nth = intval($nth);
            if(is_array($arr) && sizeof($arr) > 0 && $nth > 0){
                $arr = array_slice($arr,$nth-1, 1, true);
            }
            return $arr;
        }//end function getNthItemFromArr
```