# Best way to slice multidimensional array on the basis of keys in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an result array like this:-

```
    $array = array(
                    'key1' => array('...'),
                    'key2' => array('...'),
                    'key3' => array('...'),
                    'key4' => array('...'),
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    'keyn' => array('...')
            );
```

I need to get 5 elements from above array. first time `key1` to `key5`, `key6` to `key10`
 and so on...... On the basis of condition I need to perform operation on this.

I need output :-

```
$array = array(
                    'key1' => array('...'),
                    'key2' => array('...'),
                    'key3' => array('...'),
                    'key4' => array('...'),
                    'key5' => array('...')
            );
```

I can get value if my key value directly `$array['key1']....$array['key5']` but if key is unknown value than 
I am facing problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not quite sure of the question. Have you tried `array_slice()` and if yes, what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To iterate over such an array you can use [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/array_slice) in this manner:

```
$n = count($array);
$len = 5;
for ($i = 0; $i + $len <= $n; $i += $len) {
    $chunk = array_slice($array, $i, $len, true);
    // do work on $chunk
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: A better way is array_slice. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997653/php-get-n-th-item-of-an-associative-array) question. Example:

```
$fifthElement = array_slice($array,4,1);  //will get the 5th element
```

You can use [foreach](http://php.net/manual/de/control-structures.foreach.php) in a way that gives you the keys and the associated values. So, to get the fifth key-value-pair, you could write:

```
$i = 1;
foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
    if($i == 5)
    {
        echo "Fifth Key=".$key." value=".$value."\n";
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Geier for your quick response. I know this way but if i have 1000 element in my result array than i need to check 200 condition???

Comment: @user1978104: You're right, this method is pretty inefficient. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can just splice or slice the first 5 items off of the array.

```
<?php
 $array = array(
                    'key1' => array('...'),
                    'key2' => array('...'),
                    'key3' => array('...'),
                    'key4' => array('...'),
                    'key5' => array('...'),
                    'key6' => array('...'),
                    'key7' => array('...')
            );

$arraySlice1 = array_slice($array, 0, 5);
$arraySlice2 = array_splice($array, 0, 5);
```

Slice will leave $array intact and $array will still hold 7 items, splice will remove the returned results from $array, so $array will only hold key6 and key7

Answer (score 0):

[array_slice](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) surely works for you

```
    $first_five_elements = array_slice($array, 0, 5);
```

Here is [codepad](http://codepad.org/pnmv9jD0)