# PHP array_slice not returning array with integer keys

Tags: php, arrays, slice

Say, I've got the following code in PHP:
**included_file.php**:

```
DEFINE("MSWFFN",serialize(array(
  "mnu"=>array("n"=>"topmnu.swf","w"=>"980px","h"=>"80px","i"=>"mnu","p"=>"&subp=home")
)));
```

**main_file.php**:

```
require_once("included_file.php");
global $MSWFFN;
$MSWFFN=unserialize(MSWFFN);
$swf=array_slice($MSWFFN,0,1,false); //first swf from cfg
var_dump($MSWFFN);
var_dump($swf);
```

Based on what's said [in this question][1] and on the [php website][2] it should return an array with integer keys, but it does not.
Any idea on why does it not change the '**mnu**' key to **0**?
Output:

```
array (size=1)
  'mnu' => 
    array (size=5)
      'n' => string 'topmnu.swf' (length=10)
      'w' => string '980px' (length=5)
      'h' => string '80px' (length=4)
      'i' => string 'mnu' (length=3)
      'p' => string '&subp=home' (length=10)

array (size=1)
  'mnu' => 
    array (size=5)
      'n' => string 'topmnu.swf' (length=10)
      'w' => string '980px' (length=5)
      'h' => string '80px' (length=4)
      'i' => string 'mnu' (length=3)
      'p' => string '&subp=home' (length=10)
```

Oh, btw my Apache Version is **Apache/2.2.23 (Win32) PHP/5.3.18** (VertrigoServ v2.29)
[1]: [PHP: Get n-th item of an associative array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997653/php-get-n-th-item-of-an-associative-array)
[2]: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish that, you can use [array_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php):

```
var_dump(array_values($MSWFFN));
```

Output:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [n] => topmnu.swf
            [w] => 980px
            [h] => 80px
            [i] => mnu
            [p] => &subp=home
        )

    )
```

Comment: exactly what i wanted to accomplish! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are not using numeric keys.

> Note that array_slice() will reorder and reset the **numeric array indices** by default. You can change this behaviour by setting preserve_keys to TRUE.

There's even a [10-year-old comment](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php#26786) regarding this "surprise".

Also, for what it's worth, your output of the original variable and the output of `array_slice()` is *exactly* the same, making the latter a bit useless.

Comment: oh, guess i misunderstood that it turns the keys into numeric ones whereas it just returns the Nth element. Thank you very much!

Comment: It will modify and revert numeric keys, but it will re-match and preserve string keys. Note that numeric keys includes ones defined as strings, such as `array("12" => "Something...")`. Play around with it.