# PHP get first and forth value of an associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an associative array, `$teams_name_points`. The length of the array is unknown.

How do I access the first and forth value without knowing the key of this array in the easiest way?

The array is filled like this:

```
$name1 = "some_name1";
$name2 = "some_name2";
$teams_name_points[$name1] = 1;
$teams_name_points[$name2] = 2;
```

etc.

I want to do something like I do with an indexed array:

```
for($x=0; $x<count($teams_name_points); $x++){
    echo $teams_name_points[$x];
}
```

How do I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: Get n-th item of an associative array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997653/php-get-n-th-item-of-an-associative-array)

Comment: What do "first" and "fourth" mean in the context of an associative array?  They are not numerically indexed, so there is no specific ordering other than how items were written into the array. It sounds like you basically have a bad data structure that is not formed the way you need it to be.

Comment: @MikeBrant first meaning the item that was written into the array before all others... forth meaning the item that was written into the array after the first, second and third...... And yes, the data structure is bad, but if there is a solution to the problem, it will be more efficient to implement that solution than changing the data structure

Comment: @Marcus But from what you show in your sample, I don't understand the importance of the first and fourth items.  If you want to iterate over the array, it is as simple as `foreach($teams_name_points as $team_name => $points) {`  It would also seem you have access to the key information so if you want the points for a certain team, you would just look it up using the appropriate index.

Comment: @MikeBrant Yes, using array_keys(); solved it, as Marc B suggested.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use array_keys?

```
$keys = array_keys($your_array);

echo $your_array[$keys[0]]; // 1st key
echo $your_array[$keys[3]]; // 4th key
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `array_values` which will give you a numerically indexed array.

```
$val = array_values($arr);
$first = $val[0];
$fourth = $val[3]
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the `array_values`, to loop through as you show:

```
foreach($teams_name_points as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key = $value";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get use the array_keys function such as

```
//Get all array keys in array
$keys = array_keys($teams_name_points);


//Now get the value for 4th key
//4 = (4-1) --> 3
$value = $teams_name_points[$keys[3]];
```

You can get all values now as exists

```
$cnt = count($keys);
if($cnt>0)
{
     for($i=0;$i<$cnt;$i++)
     {
          //Get the value
          $value = $team_name_points[$keys[$i]];
     }
}
```