# Modify key and value inside multidimensional array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to modify a key and value from a multidimensional array with PHP

```
[0] => Array (
    [price] => 1-0
    [shipping] => 0-1
    [description] => 0-1
    [meta_title] => 0-1
    )
[1] => Array (
    [price] => 1-0
    [shipping] => 0-1
    [meta_title] => 0-1
    )
```

Let's say I wanna modify `description` value and key name in 0, I wanna do with index numbers for some reasons, my code so far and where I'm stucked:

```
$pageID = 0;
$text_id = 2;
$i=0;
foreach($oJson[$pageID] as $t => $f){
   if($i==$text_id){
   }
   $i++;
}
```

Desired result:

```
[0] => Array (
        [price] => 1-0
        [shipping] => 0-1
        [modified_description] => 2-3
        [meta_title] => 0-1
        )
    [1] => Array (
        [price] => 1-0
        [shipping] => 0-1
        [meta_title] => 0-1
        )
```

Thanks a lot for your precious help.

Comment: Please check this line if($p=$pageID). Here assignation is done not comparison.Just change if($p==$pageID)

Comment: Oh true, well spotted, it doesn't change anything to my question though. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you looping through the entire array instead of just accessing the key that you want to modify?

Comment: Based on what condition result of `modified_description` is `2-3`?

Comment: @Terminus That's true I modified my code

Comment: @aslawin Some variables passed through the function, point is how to change the key and value of sub array and keeping same order of keys.

Comment: Now this question appears to be asking the same as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997653/php-get-n-th-item-of-an-associative-array). (Use [array_slice](http://php.net/array_slice))

Comment: @Terminus Question is not how to access, but how to modify the key and its value and keeping same order of elements.

Comment: @ÉmilieRobert I see, didn't notice you wanted to preserve the key order, my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to keep the associative key order, you can use [array_keys](http://php.net/array_keys),  [array_values](http://php.net/array_values), and [array_combine](http://php.net/array_combine).

```
$pageID = 0;
$text_id = 2;

$newKeys = array_keys($oJson[$pageID]);
$newValues = array_values($oJson[$pageID]);

$newKeys[$text_id] = 'modified_' . $newKeys[$text_id];
$newValues[$text_id] = '2-3';

$oJson[$pageID] = array_combine($newKeys, $newValues);
```

Comment: Both answers work but I find this to be the best practical answer. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$oJson = array('0' => Array (
    'price' => '1-0',
    'shipping' => '0-1',
    'description' =>'0-1',
    'meta_title' => '0-1',
    ),
'1' => Array (
    'price' => '1-0',
    'shipping' => '0-1',
    'meta_title' => '0-1',
    )
);

$pageID = 0;
$text_id = 2;

foreach($oJson as $key => $subArray)
{
    if($key == $pageID)
    {
        $tempArray = array();
        for($i = 0; $i < count($subArray); $i++)
        {
            if($i == $text_id)
            {
                $tempArray = array_slice($subArray, 0, $text_id);
                $tempArray['modified_description'] = '2-3';
                $tempArray = array_merge($tempArray, array_slice($subArray, $text_id + 1));
            }
        }

        if(!empty($tempArray))
            $oJson[$key] = $tempArray;
    }
}


print_r($oJson);
```

**Working example: [CLICK!](https://eval.in/575585)**